# Insert Input Box Using .innerHTML property of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery for the first time. I've been searching a lot but have not gotten the answer.

I want to insert an input Type at id="star" and with value="score Star" but I'm not able to do that. Score returns the numeric value. I think the problem is in the value attribute, but I don't know where. Thanks In Advance.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#click').raty({
                    click: function(score) {
                        document.getElementById('star').innerHTML="<input type='text' name='type' value='"score+ "' Star >";
                        //alert( 'score: ' + score);

                        }
                    });
                });
</script>



          <label>Deal Type:</label>
         <div id="click"></div><span  id="star"></span></div>
```

Comment: value='"score+ "' <--- you miss a '+'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not writing the code correctly

```
.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='type' value='"score+ "' Star >";
```

It should be

```
.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='type' value='"+score+" Star' >";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not concatenating the string, or quoting the value correctly

```
.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='type' value='"score+ "' Star >";
```

should be

```
.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='type' value='" + score + " Star' >";
```

Comment: @Asad - yeah, I got that in there while you were writing the comment

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#click').raty({
                    click: function(score) {
                        document.getElementById('star').innerHTML="<input type='text' name='type' value='"+score+ " Star'>";
                        //alert( 'score: ' + score);

                        }
                    });
                });
</script>



          <label>Deal Type:</label>
         <div id="click"></div><span  id="star"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to actually create an input DOM object and append it:

```
$('#star').append($('<input/>').attr({
    type: "text",
    name: "type",
    value: score + " Star"
}));
```